# How do I concatenate raw bits/hex values onto a String in Fortran?

Tags: string, fortran

I want to do something like this (C sample):

```
char str[] = "Hello\x90\x90\xcc\x00";
```

How?

Comment: What does it do? What exact aim you want to achieve with this? I do understand it declares some character array, but what exact details you need to reproduce?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of this in Fortran would be:

`character(*), parameter :: str = "Hello"//char(144)//char(144)//char(204)//char(0)`

I made this a named (PARAMETER) constant here, but the expression for initializing would be the same in a normal assignment context. Standard Fortran doesn't allow the use of hex constants (such as `Z'90'`) as an argument to CHAR, though many compilers support that as an extension.